# Viewing reports on the web

Tags: reporting-services, visualize

I basicly want to view a report on the web. Im using Reporting Services 2008.

Also good to know is that In the report I want to view you set Multiplevalued parameters. I want to have the report viewed so that the user themselves sets these Parameters, and not in the code-behind.

Ive tried using URL access, works perfect, it renders the report just as I want. BUT.... I want to pass along a custom password to the reporting server so the user dont have to login everytime he/she wants a report. This is something I havent managed to fix.

Ive also tried using both ReportService2005.asmx and ReportExecution2005.asmx. Here the password works perfectly. BUT... The viewing of the report Ive not managed to fix.

ReportService2005.asmx: I havent found a good way here to visualize the report at all.
ReportExecution2005.asmx: In the report I want to view you need to set params in advance, I dont want to do that.

I would be very pleased to get help on this matter with suggestion on how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a public facing website? Look into SSRS security extensions. They let you override the default authentication mechanism and tie the SSRS server into your web app.

More details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155029.aspx